# Reuse Grouped User Control from Control Library in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible when reusing a UserControl from a self-made library within a WinForm to change the text of a label or a string name behind a text box?

I'm currently learning WinForms development and wanted to reuse as much code as possible.

An example:

1. Login1 UserControl

   - Username1 = login.usertextbox.text
   - Password1 = login.passtextbox.text
   - HostName1 = login.hostname.text
2. Login2 UserControl

   - Username2 = login.usertextbox.text
   - Password2 = login.passtextbox.text
   - HostName2 = login.hostname.text
3. Login.cs

   - Username, Password, Hostname (textbox) and next button

The function behind the Login User Control Library will be exactly the same, just the results from login1 and login2 should store their results in different strings etc in the form.

I see how to reuse individual controls but not if this is possible. The value of login1 will be stored under a set of strings on the winform, the next button will then hide login1 and show login2.

The login user control was designed to a specific format too, so in addition to reusing the exact same code in the background, the format should also be the same so I didn't want to use individual buttons and have to reposition the location of each control.

If this isn't possible, is there something closer to let me reuse the existing control many times?

Comment: Instead of making it simpler, you are over-complicating everything. Code re-usability is pointless if it's too hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create some public properties for your `Login` user control to expose some properties you need. For example:

```
Public string UserName 
{
    get
    {
        return UsernameTextBox.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        UsernameTextBox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

This way you can use this properties in your form, for example:

```
this.Login1.UserName
```

Another option is making your child controls public and access them directly. But using the previous method is recommended.

Comment: Let me know if the post is what you are looking for, or if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: Unbelievable how easy things can be when you know how, thanks a million. It worked a treat :) Do you know of any good resources for developing WinForms? CodeProject and MSDN etc are good for specific things but I found there was a book specifically for winform development but it was created in 2003 and I cannot find anything recent :( I'm looking specifically for best practices.

Comment: You are welcome :) At start you can take a look at resources in [winforms tag page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/winforms/info)

Comment: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647)